# Работа со словарями в текстовом файле

Tags: python, list, словари, dict

У меня текстовый файл, состоящий из множества словарей. Они не разделены запятыми. Выглядит примерно так:

```
{"op":"mcm","clk":"890423429","pt":1578998015095,"mc":[{"id":"1.167393008","marketDefinition":{"bspMarket":false}}]}
{"op":"mcm","clk":"890422329","pt":1578998015034,"mc":[{"id":"1.167393008","marketDefinition":{"bspMarket":false}}]}
{"op":"mcm","clk":"890461129","pt":1578998015021,"mc":[{"id":"1.167393008","marketDefinition":{"bspMarket":true}}]}
```

Вопрос в том, как с ним работать. Я хочу работать со словарями, искать там нужную мне информацию, делать на ее основе расчеты. На данный момент все содержимое файла - строка.

Comment: то есть, у вас в файле одна строка со множеством словарей? или у вас файл, где по словарю в каждой строке (как в вашем примере)?

Comment: нет, это одна строка

Comment: а все словари начинаются с `{"op:`?

Comment: да, все словари начинаются с {"op:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете работать с каждой строкой, как с JSON-объектом:

text.txt

```
{"op":"mcm","clk":"890423429","pt":1578998015095,"mc":[{"id":"1.167393008","marketDefinition":{"bspMarket":false}}]}
{"op":"mcm","clk":"890422329","pt":1578998015034,"mc":[{"id":"1.167393008","marketDefinition":{"bspMarket":false}}]}
{"op":"mcm","clk":"890461129","pt":1578998015021,"mc":[{"id":"1.167393008","marketDefinition":{"bspMarket":true}}]}
```

main.py

```py
import json

# читаем словари из text.txt
a = list(map(lambda line: json.loads(line), open('text.txt')))

"""
a - список, содержащий в себе 3 словаря из файла
Здесь находится работа со словарями

Чтобы убедиться, что здесь находятся именно словари, а не строки, можно добавить:

for elem in a:
    print(type(elem))
"""

# записываем отредактированные словари в text2.txt
f = open('text2.txt', 'w')
f.write('\n'.join(map(lambda elem: json.dumps(elem), a)))
```

Работает с любыми словарями в файле, если каждый записан с новой строчки (содержимое словарей не имеет значения)